# ReferenceError: Schema is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use an external schema with Mongoose in Node, but keep getting this error:

> ReferenceError: ContactSchema is not defined

My ContactSchema.js looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  address: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('ContactSchema', ContactSchema);
```

My routes.js file looks like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/choredb');

require('../models/ContactSchema.js');

var routes = function(app) {

  app.post('/createnew', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);

    var contact = new ContactSchema();
    contact.name = req.body.name;
    contact.note = req.body.note;

    contact.save(function(err){
      if (err) {throw err;}
      console.log('saved');
      mongoose.disconnect();
    });
  });

}

module.exports = routes;
```

I'm pretty sure it's not that far off, but can't figure out why it won't find the schema.

Comment: Try changing the model name to `module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);` and then instantiate it as `var contact = new Contact();`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are exporting something at "example_module", require("example_module") will return something. The code you written return Content Model, although you didn't declare as a variable.

My Way of code is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  address: String
});

var Content = mongoose.model('Content', ContentScehma);

module.exports = Content;
```

and at router or something

```
app.post("/content", function(req, res, next){
   var Content = require("../models/ContactSchema.js");
   var ContentSchema = ContentModel.schema;

   var aContent = new Content({name: "MyName", address: "MyAddress"});
   aContent.save(function(err, savedContent){
      if(err) return next(err);
      return res.send(savedContent);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to include your ContactSchema.js file in your routes.js with the following ling:

```
var db = require('../models/ContactSchema.js');
```

and then you can define your Schema in route.js like this:

```
var contact = new db.contactModel();
```

I hope this has helped you

Edit:
You also must export your schema from ContactSchema.js with the following if you use the code from above

```
var contactModel = mongoose.model('ContactSchema', ContactSchema);
exports.contactModel = contactModel;
```

If you search a very good example on how to use mongoose with node look at the following git project: https://github.com/kdelemme/blogjs